# Trying to get aspnet vnext working on a mac - missing method errors

Tags: .net, macos, mono, asp.net-core

I'm following [the instructions](https://github.com/aspnet/home#getting-started) to get a simple vNext sample working on my mac (running mavericks).

Here's what I've done:

- Using Homebrew, installed `kvm` as per the instructions (`brew tap aspnet/k` and `brew install kvm`)
- Manually downloaded and installed the latest Mono MRE from the website (3.6)
- Cloned the repo to test with the samples.
- In any of the samples (let's pick the ConsoleApp), I `k run`

I get:

```
Missing method System.Net.Sockets.Socket::.ctor(SocketType,ProtocolType) in assembly /usr/local/Cellar/kmono/3.6.1-10002/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll, referenced in assembly /Users/mattroberts/.kre/packages/KRE-mono45-x86.1.0.0-alpha4-10274/bin/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.dll
Method not found: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor'.
```

It feels like something is up with my mono config. `kvm list` reports that i'm running:

- 1.0.0-alpha4-10274   mono45  x86          /Users/mattroberts/.kre/packages

And I can mono -V which reports back as 3.6.1.

Anyone know what I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new bug it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for the message ;) I'll keep a look out for the commit that fixes this :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi looks like a fix in KRuntime issue #526 (commit f2809f3) is it [this](http://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/526)

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link to the bug, changelog/changeset, or similar?

Comment: Sorry the editor stripped the link to the issue https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/526

Comment: I just did a `kvm upgrade`, which put me onto `1.0.0-alpha4-10275`, but I get the same error. I presume I need to wait for the fix to make it out..

Comment: Yes I don't think its hit myget.org yet. In the meantime you can rollback to a working version using e.g.: kvm install 1.0.0-alpha3-10242 -p